# Add jquery multiple styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I have code I have many styles such as `("#type")` To re not prescribe a code of how you can add all in one
Sorry for bad english

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
    $(function () {
        jQuery("#type").selectbox();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: I think he wants to know how to use classes and class selectors.

Comment: I then added only (#type#) but I need to add more and (#search_category#)

Comment: jQuery("#type,#search_category").selectbox();

Comment: Now worked only #search_category#

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong, As per my understanding, you are giving styles based on the 'Id' property of the elements. In order to not repeat the creation of the styles for each and every similar element, try to use class and class selector, as @bhowden pointed out in his comment.

so, for example

```
<div>
   <p class='paragraphStyle'> This is first paragraph </p>
   <p class='paragraphStyle'> This is second paragraph </p>
</div>
```

Add a style like below in your CSS

```
.paragraphStyle { 
background-color: yellow;
}
```

And your jquery selection becomes

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
$(function () {
     jQuery(".paragraphStyle");
})
</script>
```

Let me know in case you need any more information.

Comment: I then added only (#type#) in my this code <script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
    $(function () {
        jQuery("#type").selectbox();
    })
</script> but I need to add more and (#search_category#)

Comment: As @SergeyBabayan pointed out, if you have multiple elements with different ids then u need to type all those in the multi selector. Else, you can add a dummy class to all those similar elements and select using class as shown in code above.

Comment: I tried everything you said but does not work, you can show an example of the code?

Comment: Can you please post what you tried ? With the #type and #search_category element that you are trying to select in jquery. We can find where are the issues in the code you tried.

Comment: <!--{literal}--><script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
 $(function () {
 jQuery("#type","#search_category").selectbox();
 })
 </script><!--{/literal}-->

Comment: <!--{literal}--><script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
 $(function () {
 jQuery("#type").selectbox();
 jQuery("#search_category").selectbox();
 })
 </script><!--{/literal}-->

Comment: The first code you posted should be like:               <!--{literal}--><script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript"> $(function () { **jQuery("#type,#search_category").selectbox();** }) </script><!--{/literal}-->                                                    Also, can you please post the elements that you are trying to access using jquery.